# Find All Relatives with Prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how I would return a list of everyone related to a certain person.  So, if I say relatives(A,B), A would be a person and B is a list of all of the people related to that person.  I can write any additional rules needed to assist in doing this.  Here is what I have so far.

```
man(joe).
man(tim).
man(milan).
man(matt).
man(eugene).

woman(mary).
woman(emily).
woman(lily).
woman(rosie).
woman(chris).

parent(milan, mary).
parent(tim, milan).
parent(mary, lily).
parent(mary, joe).
parent(mary, matt).
parent(chris, rosie).
parent(eugene, mary).
parent(eugene, chris).

cousins(A, B) :- parent(C, A), parent(D, B), parent(E, C), parent(E, D), not(parent(C, B)), not(parent(D, A)), A \=B.

paternalgrandfather(A, C) :- man(A), man(B), parent(B, C), parent(A, B).

sibling(A, B) :- parent(C, A), parent(C, B), A \= B.
```

Can someone guide me as to how I would go about doing this?  Thanks.

Comment: You want a recursive function that appends to the result within the recursion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you should concentrate on the 'true' relation, i.e. `parent(Old,Jung)`, other predicates are irrelevant here. The obvious assumption it's that atoms occurring in `parent/2` are identifiers (i.e. names are unique). From this picture seems that all persons here are relatives:

[image]

Then your problem should be equivalent to find all connected vertices in parent relation. You can implement a depth first visit, passing down the list of visited nodes to avoid loops (note that you need to go back to parents and down to children!), something like

```
relatives(Person, Relatives) :-
    relatives([], Person, [Person|Relatives]).

relatives(Visited, Person, [Person|Relatives]) :-
    findall(Relative, immediate(Person, Visited, R), Immediates),
    ... find relatives of immediates and append all in relatives.

immediate(Person, Visited, R) :-
    (parent(Person, R) ; parent(R, Person)),
    \+ member(R, Visited).
```

See if you can complete this snippet. Note the order of arguments in relatives/3 is choosen to easy maplist/3.

If you are willing to study more advanced code, SWI-Prolog [library(ugraph)](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%27A.28%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/ugraphs.html%27%29%29) offers a `reachable(+Vertex, +Graph, -Vertices)` predicate that does it on a list based graph representation.

Here the SWI-Prolog snippet to get the image (a file to be feed to `dot`):

```
graph(Fact2) :-
    format('digraph ~s {~n', [Fact2]),
    forall(call(Fact2, From, To), format(' ~s -> ~s;~n', [From, To])),
    format('}\n').
```

you can call in this way:

```
?- tell('/tmp/parent.gv'),graph(parent),told.
```

and then issue on command line `dot -Tjpg /tmp/parent.gv | display`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use builtin predicate findall/3 and maybe sort/2 to avoid duplicates

It would go along these lines:

```
relatives(Person, Relatives):-
  findall(Relative, is_relative(Person, Relative), LRelatives),
  sort(LRelatives, Relatives).

is_relative(Person, Relative):-
  (cousins(Person, Relative) ; paternalgrandfather(Person, Relative) ; sibling(Person, Relative)).
```

You might want to add more clauses to is_relative to get more relationships.